# String to a Format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I  have an nsstring ,see below

`NSString *Mydate=@"9/8/2011";` in month/day/year format.

I want this string to be in the format     `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

for eg:  2011-09-08 15:51:57

so that i need to show the string in a label in the later format.

Thanks all.

Comment: Your input string does not contain HH:mm:ss values.

Comment: Yes you provide input string with HH:mm:ss value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code with valid input string that will help you.

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"9/8/2011 11:10:9";
    NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtF setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:s"];
    NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:s"];
    NSString *st = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];   
    NSLog(@"%@",st);
    [dtF release];
    [dateFormat release];
```

Comment: This is fine. But I need to get only yyyy-MM-dd format from dateStr which was you created Object. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [NSDateFormatter](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/&ei=MEVnToC-CsPi4QSu-eHVDA&usg=AFQjCNG7OdpUe2UR4opTkGbz3MqJtve9Kw&sig2=_eNyqSSWtHxyNrLOm-XRtw)