# Converting the time in datetime format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

To all:

Can someone please help me about how to convert the time `(HH:mm)` format to the `datetime(yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss)` format? I need help.

I already tried this [String to a Format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332164/string-to-a-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-iphone/7332518#7332518) link, but I am having the string in this format `HH:mm` and I want to convert this into the `yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: When i am having the HH:mm value in this formate in  my database.And how to get day difference   with current time

Comment: If you are having only hour and minute i.e HH:mm in you DB then its depends upon your requirement how you deal with date. You can get today's date then replace HH:mm in the string with your DB value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@Neelz* saying right If in DB you are saving only hours & minute value then it will be depends on you which date you are using to get the formatted date.I did the same which *@Neelz* said but in different way.Below I shown the code by considering the today's date to get the date time as you need

```
   //get the today's date
    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    //Create the dateformatter object
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    //Set the required date format to get the todays date
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSString* cCurrentDateStamp = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",cCurrentDateStamp);

    //now get the hours & minute you saved in DB.I considered 11:08
    NSString *strYOurTime=@"11:08";

    //create the date time string by appending date & time
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:00",cCurrentDateStamp,strYOurTime];

     //set the formatter
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *FinalDateTime=[formatter dateFromString:str];
    NSLog(@"%@",FinalDateTime);
```

FinalDateTime is the final date which you want.Now to get the number of days between two dates refer following link:

[iPhone - get number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075356/iphone-get-number-of-days-between-two-dates)