# NSDateFormatter for this format

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to make an `NSDateFormatter` object for this date format (for example):

`2016-04-15 15:00:00`

I've tried `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` but then when I am trying to attach it to a date like that:

```
date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

It gives me `nil`.

what is the correct way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: `HH` for 24h format? And `MM` should be either on month or minutes, but whereas you put `mm` (same case) for both.

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332164/string-to-a-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-iphone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set date format as

```
2016-04-15 15:00:00
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

your date string is 24 hour format

Answer (score 0):

Here's all you need for date formatting:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

There's a list of link under the **Fixed Format** title where you can see in detail the different formats for whatever you want, for iOS7 and greater see this:

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns